# How to make Google Apps Script execute as an user accessing it without CORS error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google App Script deployed as a Web app that gets direction info based on query parameters via `DirectionFinder`.

And there is also a front end app on a different domain that sends API requests to the Web app above.

I have experimented with the deployment option and it turned out that API requests cause CORS error unless the GAS is deployed to execute as myself (NOT user accessing the web app).

Is there anyway to deploy GAS to be executed as an user accessing it?

Or is it safe to simple deploy it to execute as myself? (I fear that this will allow anonymous users to abuse my quotas)

Comment: If you deploy as "Anyone" and your requests from webapp are authenticated(has Authorization header with a Bearer token with Google drive scope), CORS won't occur.

Comment: From your issue, I thought that you might want to make users access to Web Apps using a script of Javascript. If my understanding is correct, in that case, please set it as `Execute as: User accessing the web app` and `Who has access: Anyone with Google account` when you use new IDE. And please access to Web Apps using the access token, and also share the GAS project with the users. By this, the users can access to the Web Apps as each users. It seems that this is current specification. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: I set my app to execute as `User accessing the web app` and allow access from `anyone with Google account`. I also shared my project to anyone with the link. But how to get access token for the logged-in user?Without access token I still get the CORS error. I think the problem is when sending request to GAS from the browser, it tries to redirect the browser to Google signup page. However since 3xx response does not include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in its header, so that's why it throws CORS error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed your replying just now. I apologize for this. In that case, I think that `getOAuthToken()` can be used for retrieving the access token. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken) But I'm not sure about your whole script. So I cannot propose the concrete modification point. This is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for this. By the way, when you replying to the comment, when you add `@` to the user name, I can notice your replying.

Comment: @hitochan I've just made a Web App that uses `DirectionFinder` and deployed it with `Execute as: User accessing the web` and `Who has access: Anyone with a Google account`. I tried to execute it with another account from another device. It redirected to the log-in, I logged-in with the other account, and it worked just fine. So the way you are querying the GAS is probably the problem, specifically how you acquire the token. The doc [OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#top_of_page) may be useful to you.

Comment: If that doesn't work, we'll probably need more information about your application

Comment: @Martí 
Could it be possible to share your code?

@Tanaike I need to call `getOAuthToken` in GAS script right? but the problem is I get CORS error when invoking GAS from javascript.

I made my repository public so if you can spare time I will really appreciate...
https://github.com/hitochan777/optplace-share

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed your replying just now. I apologize for this. In your case, the client is put to the outside of GAS project? If it's so, `getOAuthToken()` cannot be directly used. It is required to be careful this. In that case, it is required to retrieve the access token of each user. About this, it seems that the discussion has already been advanced. By the way, when `@` + `username` is uses 2 times, it seems that the reply is not correctly notified. Please be careful this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the support guys. Now I know I need to get access token manually, so I will try to figure out how by myself. Again, thanks so much.

Comment: @hitochan So what is your end goal? What are you trying to achieve?